# How do I copy data from an xlsx file in my google drive to a google sheet?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I have an excel file (.xlsx) saved on my google drive. I want to copy the data from there into a tab in a google sheet file i have already created. I have the following code that runs. But I don't know exactly how to specify the Google Sheet (and tab) to paste the excel data in?

``

```
function run() {
  try {

    fileName = fileName || "G:\Shared drives\ExchangeData\DailyVolumes.xlsx";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;  
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: excelFile.getName().replace(/.xlsx?/, ""),
      key: fileId
    };
    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
      convert: true
    });

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

- You want to copy the values of ".xlsx" file to the existing Google Spreadsheet.
- There is the ".xlsx" file in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the values from the Google Spreadsheet converted from the ".xlsx" file, it uses the file ID returned from `Drive.Files.insert()`.
- In your script, it is required to declare the destination Google Spreadsheet which copies the values from the ".xlsx" file and to use it.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows. Before you run the script, please set the variables of `destSpreadsheetId` and `destSheetName`.

From:

```
fileName = fileName || "G:\Shared drives\ExchangeData\DailyVolumes.xlsx";

var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
var fileId = excelFile.getId();
var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;  
var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
var resource = {
  title: excelFile.getName().replace(/.xlsx?/, ""),
  key: fileId
};
Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
  convert: true
});
```

To:

```
var destSpreadsheetId = "###";  // Added
var destSheetName = "###";  // Added

fileName = fileName || "G:\Shared drives\ExchangeData\DailyVolumes.xlsx";
var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
var fileId = excelFile.getId();
// var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id; // This is not used in your script.
var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
var resource = {title: excelFile.getName().replace(/.xlsx?/, "")};  // Modified
var sourceSpreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {convert: true});  // Modified

// Also I added below script.
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheet.id).getSheets()[0];
var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName(destSheetName);
var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- In your question, I'm not sure whether the ".xlsx" file has several sheets and the range you want to put the values. So in this modification, as a sample, the values of the 1st tab in the converted Spreadsheet are copied to the last row in the destination Spreadsheet.
- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already enabled Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### References:

- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())
- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm personally not converting an XLSX to a Sheets but I need to read an XLSX as if it was sheets. So I used your example except for the destSheet lines. Essentially, I'm opening the XLSX, getting the blob, Drive.Files.insert to a temp spreadsheet then getDataRange of that temp sheet. However this creates a new spreadsheet in my Google Drives each time I run the script. Any thoughts how to run this on the fly without actually saving the sheet?

Comment: @Royal2000H  About your question, for example, how about directly parsing the XLSX data? In this case, XmlService can be used for this. As a sample, I have already created it as Google Apps Script library. https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp But this is growing now. So when this was not what you want, I apologize for this.